# Parsing Firebase JWT claim returned from AWS API Gateway HTTP API Authorizer in Python

Tags: python, json, firebase, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

Setup: I am using AWS API Gateway HTTP API(not REST) and have configured a JWT Authorizer for the token from Firebase Authentication.

Problem: After verifying the token, API Gateway is sending decoded claims to my lambda as follows:

```json
"authorizer": {
    "jwt": {
        "claims": {
            "aud": "aud-client-id",
            "auth_time": "1603117382",
            "email": "xxxx.xxxx@gmail.com",
            "email_verified": "true",
            "exp": "1603120982",
            "firebase": "map[identities:map[email:[xxxx.xxxx@gmail.com] google.com:[123456789]] sign_in_provider:google.com]",
            "iat": "1603117382",
            "iss": "https://securetoken.google.com/project-id",
            "name": "John Doe",
            "picture": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a-/vUNKL4Y1nuA",
            "sub": "SL41gRDw1gM4to6f7HD40zushij2",
            "user_id": "SL41gRDw1gM4to6f7HD40zushij2"
        },
        "scopes": null
    }
},
```

What is the standard way of parsing the content against `firebase` key in Python?

I want to extract the id (123456789) from that content.

Is there any dict/map related Pythonic decoding or string manipulation is the way to go!

[UPDTAE]:
Seems like they are just dumping the map from Go language.

Anyways I've used `google_auth.jwt.decode(token=token, verify=False)` which only decodes and doesn't verifies, avoiding the network call for certs. which is enough for my case as verification is already done by API Gateway.